# How can I read the `ENV` file variables and run as single command in Python

Tags: python, cypress

How can I read the `dev.ENV` file and get the following five variables into the python script and run as single command in windows command prompt.

`dev.ENV file`

```
CYPRESS_baseUrl=https://someurl.com
runCyCommand=npx cypress-tags run 
tags=-e TAGS='@limitedRun' 
path=GLOB='tests/cypress/integration/**/*.feature'
config= --headless --browser chrome
```

`demoTest.py`

```
f = open("C:/Test/dev.ENV", "r")
with open("C:/Test/dev.ENV", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as my_file:  # Open file for reading
for line in my_file.readlines():  # Read all lines one-by-one
print("\nPassword: {}".format(line.strip()))
```

expected Result:
`CYPRESS_baseUrl=https://someurl.com npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@limitedRun' GLOB='cypress/integration/**/*.feature' --headless --browser chrome`

Comment: is this the correct(original) text format in perspective of TABs in your demoTest.py you added here?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code:

```py
cmd = {}
with open("C:/Test/dev.ENV", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    splitted_line = line.split('=')
    k = splitted_line.pop(0).strip('\r\n\t')
    v = '='.join(splitted_line).strip('\r\n\t')
    cmd[k] = v

print('Command is ->')

final_cmd = f"{cmd['runCyCommand']} {cmd['tags']} {cmd['path']} {cmd['config']}"

# print command
print(final_cmd)

# import os library to be able set system variables and do system calls
import os

# set env CYPRESS_baseUrl for current shell
os.environ['CYPRESS_baseUrl'] = cmd['CYPRESS_baseUrl']

print('CYPRESS_baseUrl is set to ->')

# check if ENV set
if os.name == 'nt':
  # if OS is Windows, run Windows-specific command
  # not sure if this command will work. Can't check windows behaviour
  os.system('echo %CYPRESS_baseUrl%')
else:
  # this syntax for other POSIX shells (Linux, FreeBSD or MacOS)
  os.system('echo ${CYPRESS_baseUrl}')

# run npx command
print('Run NPX ->')
os.system(final_cmd)
```

output:

```
Command is ->
npx cypress-tags run  -e TAGS='@limitedRun'  GLOB='tests/cypress/integration/**/*.feature'  --headless --browser chrome
CYPRESS_baseUrl is set to ->
https://someurl.com
Run NPX ->
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run
...
```

code is pretty easy to understand without explanation, but if you have questions, please ask.

Comment: rzlvmp Thank you, while running the script, tags and path variables are not getting retrieved...it display as follows ``CYPRESS_baseUrl=https://someurl.com npx cypress-tags run  -e TAGS GLOB --headless --browser chrome``

Comment: @soccerway Sorry, my bad :( Didn't check... Here is couple of `=` in line. Fixed code

Comment: No worries mate, now it giving error >> 'CYPRESS_baseUrl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
``'CYPRESS_baseUrl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
 CYPRESS_baseUrl=https://someurl.com npx cypress-tags run  -e TAGS='@limitedRun' GLOB='tests/cypress/integration/**/*.feature' --headless --browser chrome``

Comment: From Git bash prompt I am running like this ``python demoPy.py``

Comment: @soccerway Yes, I expected this (but couldn't check because my machine is not WIndows). That is because Windows CMD syntax is different. You should run this command at Linux or Mac inveronments. Or just google `how to set env variables in windows` and edit my code for your needs

Comment: I just tried ``os.getenv(final_cmd)```, and tried running the same and result in  ``$ python demoPy.py
$ CYPRESS_baseUrl=https://someurl.com npx cypress-tags run  -e TAGS='@limitedRun' GLOB='tests/cypress/integration/**/*.feature' --headless --browser chrome``

Comment: No errors but not running the test...

Comment: @soccerway no, that is wrong. Try to understand this [article](http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-windows-command-line-and-registry/) and change `final_cmd` according it. It should be something like `setx CYPRESS_BaseUrl someurl.com`

Comment: I think, we don't need to set anything for env...I usually run  from the root folder 
`CYPRESS_baseUrl=https://someurl.com npx cypress-tags run...` like and it will start running test windows CLI...

Comment: @soccerway ok. updated code. try new one

Comment: Getting better, it is now trying to run something, but one thing i noticed is there is no CYPRESS_baseUrl in the command that spitted out. see below

Command is:
```npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@limitedRun' GLOB='tests/cypress/integration/**/*.feature'  --headless --browser chrome
CYPRESS_baseUrl is set to ->
https://someurl.com
Run NPX ->
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "User One\AppData\Roaming```

Comment: @soccerway `CYPRESS_baseUrl` set separately. And you can see that: `CYPRESS_baseUrl is set to -> https://someurl.com`. 1. You should read basics about what is `ENV` and how to use it. 2. `npm` problem mentioned in last comment is your environment problem, I can't reproduce and solve it